# Flutter programming

Tags: flutter, dart

below is given code, and I want to call method `getLocation()` of file `home.dart` from the dart file `addLoc.dart` , and specifically, I want to call `getLocation()` method from the

```
           Container(
            height: 50,
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 0),
            child: RaisedButton(
              textColor: Colors.white,
              color: Colors.blue,
              child: Text('Use my current location'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            )
        ),
```

located in file `addLoc.dart`.

The files are as below.

`home.dart`

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  void mapCreated(controller) {
    setState(() {
      _controller = controller;
    });
  }
  List<Marker> allMarkers = [];
  GoogleMapController _controller;
  var pose;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    allMarkers.add(Marker(
        markerId: MarkerId('mk1'),
        draggable: false,
        onTap: () {
          print('Marker Tapped');
        },
        position: LatLng(21.2205, 72.8750)));
    allMarkers.add(Marker(
        markerId: MarkerId('mk2'),
        draggable: false,
        onTap: () {
          print('Marker Tapped');
        },
        position: LatLng(21.1897, 72.8270)));
  }

  Future<void> getLocation() async{
    final pose = await Geolocator().getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.best);
    setState(() {
      allMarkers.add(Marker(
          markerId: MarkerId('myLoc'),
          draggable: false,
          onTap: () {
            print('Marker Tapped');
          },
          position: LatLng(pose.latitude,pose.longitude)));
    });
    return pose;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Fire & Emergency'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/login');
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Stack(children: [
        Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          child: GoogleMap(
            initialCameraPosition:
                CameraPosition(target: LatLng(21.1702, 72.8311), zoom: 12.0),
            markers: Set.from(allMarkers),
            onMapCreated: mapCreated,
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 0, 10),
          child: FloatingActionButton(
            heroTag: "btn1",
            child: Tooltip(
              message: 'add new location',
              child: Icon(
                Icons.gps_fixed,
                color: Colors.grey[800],
              ),
            ),
            backgroundColor: Colors.brown[50],
            onPressed: () {
              getLocation();
            },
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 0, 80),
          child: FloatingActionButton(
            heroTag: "btn2",
              child: Tooltip(
                message: 'add new location',
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.location_on,
                  color: Colors.grey[800],
                  size: 30,
                ),
              ),
            backgroundColor: Colors.brown[50],
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/addLoc');
            },
          ),
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

`addLoc.dart`

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'home.dart';

// ignore: camel_case_types
class addLoc extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  _addLocState createState() => _addLocState();
}
// ignore: camel_case_types
class _addLocState extends State<addLoc> {
  MyHomePage mhp=new MyHomePage();
  TextEditingController LongCont = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController LattCont = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Fire & Emergency'),
      ),
      body:Container(
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                child: Text(
                  'Add New Location',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20,color: Colors.blue),
                )
            ),
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: TextField(
                controller: LongCont,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  labelText: 'Longitude',
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: TextField(
                controller: LattCont,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  labelText: 'Lattitude',
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
                height: 50,
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 0),
                child: RaisedButton(
                  textColor: Colors.white,
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  child: Text('Add New'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                )
            ),
            Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                child: Text(
                  'Or',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15,color: Colors.blue),
                )
            ),
            Container(
                height: 50,
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 0),
                child: RaisedButton(
                  textColor: Colors.white,
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  child: Text('Use my current location'),
                  onPressed: () {

                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                )
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: So whats the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See, there are n number of possibilities in which you can achieve the requirement, but what matter the most is how efficiently you write the code to achieve something.

In order to make use of the `getLocation()` method from `home.dart`, rather than defining the method in `home.dart` itself, *`make a separate file, call it helper.dart`* and then import the file in any page you want

**helper.dart**

```
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

class Helper{
  // If you are returning something out of the future class, try giving a 
  // dynamic if you are confused of the datatype it returns
  static Future<dynamic> getLocation() async{
    final pose = await Geolocator().getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.best);
    return pose;
  }
}
```

Then import the file and make use of it anywhere you want like this:

```
import helper.dart

// This is how you call the method from Helper class
Helpers.getLocation().then((value){
   //your operation
   setState(() {
      allMarkers.add(Marker(
          markerId: MarkerId('myLoc'),
          draggable: false,
          onTap: () {
            print('Marker Tapped');
          },
          position: LatLng(value.latitude,value.longitude)));
    });
});
```

Please read about how to use [Future Class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Future-class.html) for more insight on this. If you want to get clarified more.

> Value is nothing but the returned value from your `getLocation()` method. Future method are called with `then()`, since it first performs the operation then returns the value

Let me know, if you don't understand the concept or any problem you face. Happy learning